# Oracle on Rails [Windows 10]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, oracle

I have a problem using Rails to connect to the oracle database.. I configured the oracle instant client, everything working but when I start the rails application it shows the following error

**RuntimeError
No DLL is found to hook.**

Information:

-ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x64-mingw32]

-Rails 5.2.6

-ruby-oci8 (2.2.9-x64-mingw32)

```
RuntimeError (No DLL is found to hook.):

ruby-oci8-2.2.9-x64 (mingw32) lib/oci8/properties.rb:74:in `__set_prop'
ruby-oci8-2.2.9-x64 (mingw32) lib/oci8/properties.rb:74:in `[]='
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (5.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/oci_connection.rb:322:in `new_connection'
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (5.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/oci_connection.rb:386:in `initialize'
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (5.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/oci_connection.rb:31:in `new'
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (5.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/oci_connection.rb:31:in `initialize'
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (5.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/connection.rb:11:in `new'
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (5.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/connection.rb:11:in `create'
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (5.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:74:in `oracle_enhanced_connection'
activerecord (5.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:830:in `new_connection'
activerecord (5.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:874:in `checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (5.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:853:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (5.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:814:in `acquire_connection'
activerecord (5.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:538:in `checkout'
activerecord (5.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:382:in `connection'
activerecord (5.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1033:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (5.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:118:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (5.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:90:in `connection'
activerecord (5.2.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:554:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (5.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (5.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
railties (5.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
railties (5.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:706:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

My database.yml config (Hiding information such as port, ip):

```
default: &default
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

    development:
      <<: *default
      adapter: oracle_enhanced
      database: SID
      username: USER
      password: PASSWORD
      host: IP
      port: PORT
```

Comment: Please provide more details. What does "I go to upload the rails application" mean? what is the stacktrace for the error, etc.

Comment: Sorry, i have detailed more.. When I start rails with rails server and access localhost:3000, shows this error

Comment: Check that SQL*Plus from Instant Client can connect to your database.  Make sure you have the right VS Redistributable.  Check that Instant Client is in your PATH and that you have restarted command windows etc if you have change environment variables.

Comment: Sqlplus worked.
I tried to config using WSL using linux instant client and it worked, but i need to config in Windows without WSL

Comment: A couple of things. Make sure you have the instant client from oracle installed, and make sure you have the same bit version installed as your ruby i.e. you may need to install both the 32bit and 64bit on your machine